# How to declare a link without any content?

Tags: html, css

I want to declare a link without any content, instead I want to use a background image for it. But I can see the background only when I put something between `<a></a>` tags. How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make the link a block-level element, and give it a width and height:

```
a.somelink {
    display: block;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
    background-image: url(someimage.png)
}
```

Or just use an `<img />` inside the `<a>` instead of using a `background-image`.

Comment: thank you so much,it works.but my table is tearing apart with that!
i want something to take place over my original image(this background is different from background of my link,this is the original image that i want to put my link over it).
how can i do it?

Comment: @armin that kind of info should be in your question, and should be there in the first place. Please update your question and give a full overview of what you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

A link should always have text, whether it is direct text content or the `alt` tag of an image. You can use a negative `text-indent` style to hide the text from view, replacing it with the image. Example:

```
<a href="page.html" id="important-link">check out my important stuff</a>

#important-link {
    background: transparent url(../images/important-stuff.png) no-repeat top left;
    display: block; /* needed as <a> tag is inline by default */
    height: 100px; /* whatever image width is */
    text-indent: -9999px; /* moves the text off the screen */
    width: 100px; /* whatever image height is */
}
```

This is a common technique for image replacement where specific fonts are needed, while preserving accessibility (mostly, CSS+no images is the only caveat) and SEO benefits from the text.

Comment: you have fired me dude! so +1 ;-)

Comment: thank you so much,it works.but my table is tearing apart with that! i want something to take place over my original image(this background is different from background of my link,this is the original image that i want to put my link over it). how can i do it?

Comment: @armin that makes very little sense, can you create a small test case?

Answer (score 1):

Best practice and **`SEO`** friendly **`CSS`** *Text Replacement With Images:*

> http://css-tricks.com/css-image-replacement/

Answer (score 0):

To use a background image, give it a style of `display: block;` or `display: inline-block;` depending what you're after.

Example HTML:

```
<a href="#" class="ImgLink"></a>
```

CSS:

```
a.ImgLink {
  display: block; 
  background: #FFFFFF url(img.jpg); 
  width: 200px; 
  height: 100px;
}
/* Add a hover if you want */
a.ImgLink:hover {
  background: #FFFFFF url(imgHover.jpg); 
}
```

Comment: thank you so much,it works.but my table is tearing apart with that! i want something to take place over my original image(this background is different from background of my link,this is the original image that i want to put my link over it). how can i do it?

Comment: @armin - You want the link to replace the background of the cell it's in?  And if so are you using any javascript framework?

Answer (score 0):

What about this:

```
<a href="#>&nbsp;</a>
```

then remove the possible underline with the following css:

```
a.somelink {
    display: block;
    text-decoration:none;
    background-image: url(someimage.png)
}
```